# SwiftUI view updates even if it does not depend on a dynamic property

Tags: swiftui

I created an `ObservableObject` that gathers data and a view that depends on this object. More specifically some parts of the UI depend on one property of it and other parts depend on other properties.

The way `ObservableObject` works is that if **any** of its `Published` property gets updated (event if it does not change) it sends an `objectWillChange` notification that triggers updates for subscribed views.

However, I did expect that only the parts of the views that depends on an `ObservableObject` property that actually changed would be updated, not the entire view because body computations are expensive.

Unfortunately this it not the behavior I observed during my experiments. For instance in the following code the `List` view depends only on the `color` dynamic property of the `ObservedObject` "preferences" and the `TextField` updates only the `text` property of the observed object. I observed with the `debugPrint`'s that when I type text the List and its rows gets updated each time even if it does not depend on `text`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var list = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    @StateObject private var preferences = Preferences()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(list, id: \.self) { element in
                Text(element)
                    .foregroundColor(preferences.color)
                    .debugPrint("Row view updated")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                TextField("Text", text: $preferences.text)
                    .debugPrint("Text field view updated")
                
                Button("Toogle Color", action: toggleColor)
                    .debugPrint("Button view updated")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .debugPrint("Content view updated")
    }
    
    func toggleColor() {
        preferences.color = [.blue, .green, .orange, .red].randomElement()!
    }
}

final class Preferences: ObservableObject {
    @Published var color: Color = .blue
    @Published var text: String = ""
}

extension View {
    func debugPrint(_ elements: Any...) -> Self {
        #if DEBUG
        print(elements)
        return self
        #else
        return self
        #endif
    }
}
```

**Is this the correct and intended behavior? How the optimal behavior I described above could be obtained, i.e. not calling `body` when the `ObservedObject` changes but only the components that depends on specific properties?**

I observed in bigger SwiftUI projects that this behavior can greatly slow down the application and is not easily debuggable because unique state is often enforced through heavy `ObservedObject`s (or `StateObject`) injected at the root view and used in many places. **I Observed this behavior even with small lists of components with heavy UI layout.**

**Note 1:** I was bugged by the `StateObject` definition which suggests that only the views that depend on those properties are updated (and not when the `StateObject` changes).

> SwiftUI creates a new instance of the object only once for each
> instance of the structure that declares the object. When published
> properties of the observable object change, SwiftUI updates the parts
> of any view that depend on those properties [...]

**Note 2:** The issue totally disappear if I define the `List` in its own component, the rendering is fast:

```swift
struct ListView: View {
    let list: [String]  // Also works with a @Binding
    
    let color: Color  // Also works if it would be `preferences`
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(list, id: \.self) { element in
                Row(text: element, color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why in this case the view updates are fast?

Comment: You misinterpreted 'updated' with 'created'... `body` is a function, so everything inside executed line by line... the documentation states about calling `body` of sub-views - that means update. So sub-view is created, because its constructor is part of parent view body, but its body is not called, ie sub-view is not updated, if it does not depend on anything changed.

Comment: I don't thing this is what I mean. If you take my code, use a bigger list (say 100.000 elements) and then profile the app in release mode you'll see that typing a letter in the text field is really slow because the list body is re-computed each time.

Comment: Is there an actual real world use case for displaying 100.000 elements on device? There are also lots of ways to optimise starting with lazy views. Evaluation of the body is not equivalent to rendering it as well. How do you know the view gets redrawn?

Comment: No, it's a contrived example for illustration purpose but it actually occurs in real applications where there is fewer elements but the body computation is heavy (network calls, sorting, views with images, async operations, etc...). I write this SO because I encountered and solved this issue in a real project. You can monitor body invocations (i.e. view updates) with Xcode SwiftUI profiler.

Comment: Body invocations are not equivalent to rerendering and it is a very important thing to understand about SwiftUI. There should be no network calls sorting etc in your Views. This logic needs to be handled elsewhere.

Comment: Keep in mind body has a 10 View limit to force you to break it up into smaller View thus tighten invalidation.